# Unexpected ng-repeat array results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I found out that array ordering is not guaranteed. I therefore added a dynamic number and nested the objects in the array so as to be able to use the numbering to get the items out in order. When I console.log I get the items in the correct order but when in the view they appear in another order.

I have the following view :

```
<div id="objectives-report-single" ng-repeat="(key,value) in widgetItems">
        <tr ng-repeat="(keyInner,valueInner) in value">
            <td class="accountName">{{keyInner}}</td>
            <td class="accountValue">{{valueInner}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The following JS:`

```
                var n = 0;
                var dynamicObject;
                scope.widgetItems = {};
                angular.forEach(scope.report.executeResult.rowData, function (i) {

                var a = scope.report.executeResult.rowData[n].values[0].value;
                var name = 'a';

                dynamicObject = {
                    [eval(name)]: scope.report.executeResult.rowData[n].values[1].value
                };

                scope.widgetItems[n] = dynamicObject;
                n++;
            });`
```

[image: console.log][image: actual result]

Comment: Array ordering *is* guaranteed. *Object* ordering is not.

Comment: yes, I have tried to order the objects in the array-> without success, so mix of the two

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I added them to an array of objects that were numbered and then looped through this in an inner ng-repeat. Therefore I used the principle that an array is ordered but objects in JS aren't.

```
    <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="(keyInner,valueInner) in value">
            <td class="accountName">{{keyInner}}</td>
            <td class="accountValue">{{valueInner}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

            var n = 0;
            scope.dynamicObject = {};
            scope.widgetItems = [];
            angular.forEach(scope.report.executeResult.rowData, function (i) {

                var a = scope.report.executeResult.rowData[n].values[0].value;
                var name = 'a';

                scope.dynamicObject = {
                    [eval(name)]: scope.report.executeResult.rowData[n].values[1].value
                };

                scope.widgetItems[n] = scope.dynamicObject;
                n++;


            });
```